# How to jump from program to exit in windows batch

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am running two batch Java classes fron windows batch file in a sequence. I want to give an option to exit after the first class is run; after the first pause statement.

How do I use jump to terminate the program if the user wants to close it without using the close button on GUI?

Also, can PAUSE e customised to change its default message?

```
@ECHO off
color 0E


ECHO Running prog.....
ECHO Step 1 commences....

java -cp D:\proj\bin;D:\proj\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar com.Class1

ECHO Please ensure modem is on and press any key!
ECHO Step 2 commences....

PAUSE

:: Give option to exit

java -cp D:\proj\bin com.Class

echo Completed program.....

PAUSE
```

Comment: You can use `>nul` after the `pause` so `pause>nul` to make it not print `press any key to continue . . .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize `PAUSE`'s message, you can `ECHO` the message you wish to display, then pipe `PAUSE`'s output to `NUL`:

```
echo Please press any key on your keyboard to continue with this program
pause>nul
```

To exit your batch file between the two Java program execution, you can do the following:

```
@ECHO off
color 0E

ECHO Running prog.....
ECHO Step 1 commences....

java -cp D:\proj\bin;D:\proj\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar com.Class1

SET /P __ANSWER_=Do you wish to continue? (y/n)
IF /I %__ANSWER_% EQU N GOTO :EOF

ECHO Please ensure modem is on and press any key!
ECHO Step 2 commences....

PAUSE

:: Give option to exit

java -cp D:\proj\bin com.Class

echo Completed program.....

PAUSE
```

You can replace the `GOTO :EOF` command with a `GOTO` to a specific label if you with to display something to the user before ending the batch file execution.