# How would I run these programs from ant

Tags: java, ant

I have this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582724/how-to-jump-from-program-to-exit-in-windows-batch) for the batch file. I have come to know that instead of this drudge I can automate this by Ant; which is what the tool is about I heard.

I want to run this two classes and I have some questions,

- Do I need two `run` task because I need to run these programs separately one after the other?
- How will I run this program if I `jar` it? Would I need two `dist` task to create separate jars? The thing is I have two entry points from these?

Comment: With Ant you can use the [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

Comment: Why do you want to use Ant? If you're not building Java programs, using Ant will actually make things more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick sample build.xml that will build, jar and run.  Assuming you have Ant installed, then just run ant in the base folder and it will do the rest.  My output shown below.

```
<project name="myproject" basedir="." default="all">

<property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="dist.dir" value="${basedir}/dist"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="jar.name" value="myjar.jar"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property file="${basedir}/build.properties"/>

<target name="all" depends="clean, compile, jar, run"/>

<target name="clean" description="cleans all build directories">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" description="compiles the project">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="on" deprecation="on" optimize="on" fork="true" memoryMaximumSize="256m">
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" description="Jars the files and signs the jar file">
    <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/${jar.name}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" description="runs tasks">
    <echo>Running task 1</echo>
     <java classname="test.Main1">
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="${build.dir}/${jar.name}"/>
     </classpath>
   </java>
   <echo>Running task 2</echo>
   <java classname="test.Main2">
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="${build.dir}/${jar.name}"/>
     </classpath>
   </java>
</target>
</project>
```

Here's src for Main1.  Main2 just changes Main1 to Main2
package test;

```
public class Main1  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Task 1...");
    }
}
```

Output:
    c:\Customers\StackOverflow>ant
    Buildfile: build.xml

```
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory c:\Customers\StackOverflow\build

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\Customers\StackOverflow\build\classes
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to c:\Customers\StackOverflow\build\classes

jar:
  [jar] Building jar: c:\Customers\StackOverflow\build\myjar.jar

run:
    [echo] Running task 1
    [java] Task 1...
    [echo] Running task 2
     [java] Task 2...

 all:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

c:\Customers\StackOverflow>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<sequential>

<!-- call target1 -->
<!-- call target2 -->

</sequential>
```